# Laptop speaker is not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, samsung

Inbuilt speaker of my laptop is not working. Literally, there are no sounds.

My laptop : [Samsung NT950SBE-X716](https://www.samsung.com/sec/pc/notebook-nt950sbe-x716/NT950SBE-X716/)

I gathered the following information which seems to be helpful.

1. [Setting-Sound screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khr3o.png)
2. [`sudo alsamixer` screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1fnX.png)
3. `lspci` result

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df9 (rev 11)
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9dfc (rev 11)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9ded (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 9def (rev 11)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df0 (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9de8 (rev 11)
00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9dea (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9de0 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9dbc (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db4 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db0 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d84 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9da3 (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9da4 (rev 11)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
03:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
37:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
6c:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
6d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install pavucontrol:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

goto output devices, in built in Audio, select port as Speakers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pulse audio volume control in a terminal with:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

then launch it in a terminal with

```
pavucontrol & exit
```

Mess with the output device settings and see if you get sound.